# Chebyshev inequality for standard deviation

Tags: linear-algebra, standard-deviation

everyone!
I have a question when I studied matrices of norm and distance.
Chebyshev inequality for  standard deviation.

If $k$ is the number of entries of $x$ that satisfy 
$$
|x_i - \operatorname{avg}(x)| \ge a,
$$
then 
$$
k/n \le (\operatorname{std}(x)/a)^2.
$$
This inequality is only interesting for 
$$
a \gt \operatorname{std}(x)
$$

Could you tell me how can we get this inequality.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the non-probabilistic (statistical) version of the Chebyshev inequality.

Let $S$ be the "tail set": $i\in S \iff |x_i - \overline{x}|\ge a$, and let $|S|=k$. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})^2= \sum_{i\in S} (x_i - \overline{x})^2+\sum_{i\notin S} (x_i - \overline{x})^2=\\
\ge \sum_{i\notin S} (x_i - \overline{x})^2
\ge k \,a^2
$$

Then, defining the sample variance $s_n^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})^2/ n $ we get:

$$ \frac{k}{n}  \le \frac{s_n^2}{a^2}$$

The analogous probabilistic inequality is

$$ Pr(|x-u|\ge a) \le \frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}$$

Comment: You're welcome. If you are new here, read this http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers